# Параллельная и последовательная обработка в ansible

Tags: ansible

Вопрос вообще возник из того, что при клонировании крупных репозиториев вижу, что порядок вывода на экран меняется.

Ну, чтобы не быть голословным, - конкретный пример для ansible 2.1

Набор данных:

```
  repositories:
    mediawiki_core1:
      repo: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git
      path: w1
    mediawiki_core2:
      repo: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git
      path: w2
      version: REL1_25
    mediawiki_core3:
      repo: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git
      path: w3
```

Обработчик:

```
- name: clone repositories
  git:
   repo: "{{ item.value.repo }}"
   dest: "/root/tests/{{ item.value.path }}/"
   version: "{{ item.value.version | default('HEAD') }}"
  become: true
  become_user: apache
  with_dict: "{{ repositories }}"
```

Вывод окажется таким:

> TASK [abcdef : clone repositories]
>
> ---
>
> changed: [server.domain.ru] => (item={'value': {u'repo':
>   u'https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git', u'path':
>   u'w1'}, 'key': u'mediawiki_core1'})
>
> changed: [server.domain.ru] => (item={'value': {u'repo':
>   u'https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git', u'path':
>   u'w3'}, 'key': u'mediawiki_core3'})
>
> changed: [server.domain.ru] => (item={'value': {u'repo':
>   u'https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/core.git', u'path':
>   u'w2', u'version': u'REL1_25'}, 'key': u'mediawiki_core2'})

Нужно сделать так, чтобы гарантированно выполнить последовательно задачи одну за другой -- вне зависимости от того, сколько длится её выполнение.

Типичный пример: после того, как клонируется движок вики (очень длительная задача), можно приступать к клонированию множества мелких репозиториев со скринами и экстеншнами.

Дополнительно, хочется навести порядок в голове и разобраться, как управлять порядком выполнения, чтобы уметь распараллеливать задачи, если нужно, но и если нужно гарантировать, что задачи выполнятся одна за другой в указанном порядке, то уметь выполнять их последовательно.

P.S. Что самое странное: именно в приведённом примере проблема с порядком возникает, а вот когда запускаешь разные репозитории (первым -- тяжёлый медиавики, вторым -- небольшой собственный репозиторий), проблема перестаёт воспроизводиться: сначала долго отрабатывает первый таск, потом быстро пролетает второй. 
В мистику не верю: это просто говорит о непонимании, как оно всё работает под капотом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понял гоняя допонительные тесты, дело вообще не в том, сколько по времени выполняется задача внутри `dict` -- а в том, что сортировка для `dict` не гарантирована. Об этом было в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414055/how-to-enforce-the-order-of-with-dict-in-ansible) на большом СО.

Точнее, обход `with_dict` проходит по `dict` не в том порядке, в котором я указываю элементы: идёт внутренняя сортировка по значению хеша.

Для того, чтобы обходить элементы в том порядке, в котором я записал их - нужно заменять `dict` на `items` и обход делать не `with_dict`, а `with_items`.

```
  vars:
    with_dict_test:
      - { key: 'one', value: 1 }
      - { key: 'two', value: 2 }
      - { key: 'three', value: 3 }
      - { key: 'four', value: 4 }
      - { key: 'five', value: 5 }
  tasks:
    - name: with_dict test
      debug: msg="{{item.key}} --> {{item.value}}"
      with_items: "{{ with_dict_test }}"
```

Или, точный пример, как у меня в вопросе:

```
  vars:
    with_dict_test:
      - { repo: 'url1', path: 'A', version: 'REL1_25' }
      - { repo: 'url2', path: 'B' }
  tasks:
    - name: with_dict test
      debug: msg="{{item.repo}} --> {{item.path}} -- {{ item.version | default ('HEAD') }}"
      with_items: "{{ with_dict_test }}"
```

И что-то мне такая форма сильно напоминает ;) Открываем [документацию, раздел Standard Loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops) и видим:

> Note that the types of items you iterate over with ‘with_items’ do not
>   have to be simple lists of strings. If you have a list of hashes, you
>   can reference subkeys using things like:
>
> ```
> - name: add several users
>   user: name={{ item.name }} state=present groups={{ item.groups }}
>   with_items:
>     - { name: 'testuser1', groups: 'wheel' }
>     - { name: 'testuser2', groups: 'root' }
> ```

Вот так совсем хорошо:

```
with_dict_test:
  - { repo: 'url1'
    , version: 'REL1_25'
    , path: 'A' }
  - { repo: 'url2'
    , path: 'B' }
```